How do you fit/learn a nonstationary Poisson process from data using maximum likelihood estimation?
I'm trying to understand how to fit/learn a nonstationary Poisson process from data. Through this question, I will explain how I understand the Poisson process, the nonstationary variation of it, and how it applies to my problem space. Ultimately I am looking to understand where I am going wrong, and any thoughts are appreciated!
My Application
Why? I have a set of webstore visit data arrival times, and ultimately I would like to simulate visits to the webstore.
The arrival process naturally can be modeled as a Poisson process. I can use maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) to fit a Poisson process to this data. However, since the arrival rates change throughout the day, this problem seems better suited to a nonstationary Poisson process. I cannot find any resources on how to use MLE to fit such a process.
I will demonstrate below how I solve the problem for a standard Poisson process model, and the work I do toward a nonstationary Poisson process.
Standard Poisson Process
Let the arrival time data be $$ \left\{t_0, t_1, t_2,\ldots,t_N\right\}$$ so that the interarrival times are $$ A_i = t_i - t_{i-1} , \; i=1,2,\ldots,N $$
For a standard Poisson process, we know that the interarrival times are exponentially distributed with a constant parameter $\lambda$, so that the probability of observing the interarrival time $A$ is $$ \text{P}_{\lambda}\left(A\right) = \lambda e^{-\lambda A} $$
Thus, the likelihood of observing our dataset is $$ L\left(\lambda\right) = \prod_{i=1}^N P_{\lambda}\left(A_i\right) = \lambda^N \exp \left(-\lambda \sum_{i=1}^N A_i \right)$$
Following the standard program of MLE, we take the logarithm
$$ \ln L\left(\lambda\right) = N \ln \lambda - \lambda \sum_{i=1}^N A_i $$
and seek the parameter value, $\lambda^*$, that maximizes this quantity:
$$ \lambda^* = \arg \max_{\lambda} \left\{ N \ln \lambda - \lambda \sum_{i=1}^N A_i \right\}$$
One further simplification is that the final sum "telescopes":
$$ \lambda^* = \arg\max_{\lambda} \left\{ N \ln \lambda - \lambda \left(t_N - t_0 \right)\right\}$$
We can solve for this value by taking the derivative and setting it to zero. Skipping the simple algebra, we end up with $$ \lambda^* = \left( \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N A_i \right)^{-1} = \left( \frac{t_N - t_0}{N} \right)^{-1} $$
which is, satisfyingly, the inverse of the sample's mean observed interarrival time.
Example
I will simulate some simple data and pretend that it's my real webstore arrival data.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def generate_arrival_times(lambda_: float, T: float) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    """Given a constant arrival rate lambda_, simulate some arrival data.
    This generates some data that looks sort of like my real webstore data.

    Returns
        np.ndarray: arrival times array
        np.ndarray: interarrival times array. These are exponentially distributed.
    """
    arrival_times = [ 0 ]   # first arrival at t0 = 0
    while True:
        # get next interarrival time
        A_i = np.random.exponential(1/lambda_)
        t_i = arrival_times[-1] + A_i
        if t_i > T:
            break
        arrival_times.append(t_i)
    t = np.array(arrival_times)
    A = t[1:] - t[:-1]
    return t, A

lambda_actual = 5.0
arrival_times, interarrival_times = generate_arrival_times(lambda_=lambda_actual, T=50)

Next, calculate the maximum likelihood estimate, $\lambda^*$. We will plot the pdf of the fitted exponential against the histogram of the observed interarrival times:
lambda_star = len(interarrival_times) / (arrival_times[-1] - arrival_times[0])
print(f"lambda actual: {lambda_actual:.3f}")
print(f"lambda star:   {lambda_star:.3f}")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
plt.hist(x=interarrival_times, density=True, label='actuals')
x_ = np.linspace(0,1, 100)
pdf = lambda x: lambda_star * np.exp(-lambda_star * x)
ax.plot(x_, pdf(x_), label='MLE estimate')
ax.legend()
ax.set(xlabel=r'$A_i$', ylabel='observed freq')
plt.show()

For me this output
lambda actual: 5.000
lambda star:   4.692


which, informally, looks like a fairly good fit!
Nonstationary Poisson Process
We now drop the assumption that the arrival rate is independent of time, so we have $$ \lambda = \lambda\left(t\right). $$
For example, ignoring time zones and so on, I expect that we will have more visits to the webstore during the second half of the day, so the data could be modeled as a step function like:
def lambda_(t):
    """Time-varying arrival rate."""
    return (t < 6) * 3.0 + (6 <= t) * 10.0
t = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2))
ax.plot(t, lambda_(t))
ax.set(xlabel=r'$t$', ylabel=r'$\lambda\left(t\right)$')
plt.show()


Here is my (roughly-simulated) data:
T = 12
t = 0

arrival_times = [np.random.exponential(1/lambda_(t))]
while True:
    A = np.random.exponential(1/lambda_(t)) # sample
    t = arrival_times[-1] + A
    if t > T:
        break
    else:
        arrival_times.append(t)

arrival_times = np.array(arrival_times)
plt.scatter(arrival_times, np.ones_like(arrival_times))

This is where things become tricky: what is the likelihood function for this process? In analogue with the first example, we need the probability of observing the $i$-th arrival at $t_i$. Equivalently, this is asking for the probability of observing the interarrival time $A_i = t_i - t_{i-1}$.
Unlike in the standard Poisson process, we cannot guarantee that the interarrival times are exponentially distributed. The interarrival time $A_i$ will be observed if no arrival happens between times $t_{i-1}$ and $t_i$. That is, the probability of observing arrival time $t_i$ depends on $t_{i-1}$.
It seems common to define the mean function (or cumulative rate function) $\Lambda$ as $$ \Lambda\left(t\right) = \int_{0}^t \lambda\left(u\right) \, du $$
Then I have seen the probability of observing the $i$-th interarrival time given as:
\begin{align*}
\text{Pr}\left(A_i \, \middle| \, t_{i-1}\right) & = \lambda\left(t_{i-1}+A_i \right) e^{-\left[ \Lambda\left(t_{i-1} + A_i\right) - \Lambda\left(t_{i-1}\right)\right]} \\
& = \lambda\left(t_{i}\right) e^{-\left[ \Lambda\left(t_{i}\right) - \Lambda\left(t_{i-1}\right)\right]} \\
\end{align*}
so the likelihood of the entire dataset is
\begin{align*}
L\left(\lambda\right) & = \prod_{i=1}^N \text{Pr}\left(A_i\,\middle|\,t_{i-1}\right) \\
& = \prod_{i=1}^N \lambda\left(t_i\right)e^{-\left[ \Lambda\left(t_i\right) - \Lambda\left(t_{i-1}\right) \right]} \\
& = \left[\prod_{i=1}^N \lambda\left(t_i\right) \right]e^{-\left[ \Lambda\left(t_N\right) - \Lambda\left(t_{0}\right) \right]} \\
\end{align*}
where in the last line the sum in the exponential "telescoped" nicely. As usual we can take the logarithm to simplify things:
$$ \log L\left(\lambda\right) = \sum_{i=1}^N \log \lambda\left(t_i\right) - \left[\Lambda\left(t_N\right) - \Lambda\left(t_0\right) \right] $$
Note here that if $\lambda\left(t\right) = \lambda$ is constant, then $ \Lambda\left(t\right) = \lambda t$ and we obtain the exact same log-likelihood as in the previous case; this gives me confidence that I'm on the right track.
To perform MLE, we no longer have $\lambda$ as the parameter to optimize over, but rather we require a parametric form for $\lambda = \lambda\left(t\right)$.
I will choose an exponential form: $$ \lambda\left(t\right) = ae^{bt}$$ and seek parameter values $a,b$ to maximize the log-likelihood above.
Analytical Attempt
With this choice of $\lambda\left(t\right)$, we obtain $$ \Lambda\left(t\right) = \left.\frac{a}{b}e^{bu}\right|_0^t = \frac{a}{b}\left(e^{bt} - 1\right) $$
by integration. The log-likelihood becomes
$$ \log L\left(\lambda\right) = N \log a + b\sum_{i=1}^N t_i - \frac{a}{b}\left(e^{bt_N} -e^{bt_0} \right)$$
The next step would be to take partial derivatives with respect to $a$ and $b$, set them equal to zero, and solve the resulting nonlinear system of equations for $a$ and $b$. However, this seems analytically impossible.
Numerical Attempt
Instead, I will try to use numerical methods to find the optimal values of these parameters.
I first set up the negative log-likelihood function to be minimized:
def neg_log_likelihood(params):
    # Negative log-likelihood function to be minimized
    alpha, beta = params
    lambda_ = lambda t_arr: alpha * np.exp(beta * t_arr)
    Lambda_ = lambda t_arr: (alpha / beta) * ( np.exp(beta * t_arr) - 1 )
    
    like = np.sum(np.log(lambda_(arrival_times[1:])))
    like = -(Lambda_(arrival_times[-1]) - Lambda_(arrival_times[0]))
    return -1*like

I then use scipy to perform the optimization, and apply the constraint that $a$ should be positive so that $\lambda \geq 0$.
from scipy.optimize import minimize
res = minimize(
    fun=neg_log_likelihood,
    x0=[0.1, 0.1],
    constraints=[
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda params: params[0]},
    ]
    )
res.x

This always results in numerical issues: either overflow or divide-by-zero errors.
Question
Is my problem not formulated correctly --- i.e., is my likelihood function wrong? --- or are these expected numerical issues that I'm running into? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

At a quick skim I didn't see any problems with the math you presented. I expect you're going to need to dig more into (1) selecting an optimizer and (2) tweaking the chosen optimizer to behave well. Another approach might be to re-express the objective in a way that preserves order (esp' optima). scipy.optimize.minimize offers a lot of configuration, including supplying your own optimizer as long as it is compliant with its API.
